# $n$ people place their phone into a bag. Each person randomly picks a mobile phone from the bag

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, inclusion-exclusion

The question is split into two parts.

1. Determine an expression for the probability that at least one individual selects their own mobile phone. Let $L(n)$ denote this expression.
2. Determine the exact value of $lim_{n\to\infty}L(n)$.

I did the first part as follows:

The sample space is $|\Omega|=n!$, the number of different ways the phones can be distributed among the participants. Let $A$ be the event that no person selects their phone and $A_i$ the event that person $i$ doesn't select their phone. Then $$P(A)=P(A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n)$$$P(A^c)$ would be the probability that at least one person selects their phone and $P(A_i^c)$ the probability that person $i$ does select their phone with $|A_i^c|=(n-1)!$. Then $P(A_i^c)=\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}$ and $P(A_{i_1}^c\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_k}^c)=\frac{(n-k)!}{n!}$ and via de Morgan and inclusion exclusion $$P(A^c)=P(A_1^c\cup\cdots\cup A_n^c)=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\sum_{1\leq i_1<\cdots<i_k\leq n}P(A_{i_1}^c\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_k}^c)$$ For the inclusion exclusion we use the fact that $$\sum_{1\leq i_1<\cdots<i_k<n}P(A_{i_1}^c\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_k}^c)={n\choose k}P(A_{i_1}^c\cap\cdots\cap A_{i_k}^c)$$ Substituting all of this into the inclusion exclusion formula yields \begin{align*}P(A^c)&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(n-k)!}{n!}{n\choose k}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{(n-k)!}{n!}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{1}{k!}\\&=L(n)\end{align*}
As with any probability question without answeres, I am not very confident in my answer. This is especially so considering that the second question asks for the exact value of an infinite series containing $(-1)^{k-1}$. I know that it will most likely converge to some value but I have no clue how.

Comment: See [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).  For what it's worth, I may be mistaken, but I suspect that recursion provides an alternative approach to the problem.

Comment: With regards to the value of an infinite series... recall that $\text{exp}(x)$ is defined as $1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ (*equivalently, having started from zero assuming you are comfortable with $0^0=1$*).  You are expected to be familiar with the number $e$ at this point.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you that helped

Comment: @JMoravitz I am very much familiar with $e$ :) and thanks for the reminder